# Export Openstreetmap to OSM with English name tag

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill

Is there anyway to export an openstreetmap that has a english name tag to OSM with the english names on things ?
My problem is that I can find a map on openstreetmap for Jerusalem and I can see that there exists english street tags but when I export the map to OSM and use in other tools like Tilemill all the street names are written in the default language Hebrew, how do I get the names in english ?

Answer (score 0):

Most exports/extracts will always contain all [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). So it is very likely that your export already contains the english names (tagged with *name:en*) but the software isn't using them but the regular *name* tag instead.

Have you looked into the exported file in order to verify if it contains elements tagged with *name:en*?